How to use cucumber-jvm to create live data?
I drove the development of my system through cucumber tests very successfully. Now the system is ready to be tested through a UI, and I would like to re-use the test data from my scenarios for this. Is it possible to trigger executing the appropriate @Whens of my step definitions when starting up my system?

Have you tried extracting the code from your steps into methods and then invoking those methods from your step definitions and your new test setup? The step definitions are there mostly to glue the Gherkin steps to executable code. They're not really made for reuse by other parts of your tests.

It's mostly not the code from the StepDefinitions that I want to reuse, but the data from the gherkin files and the logic that puts them into DataTables and calls the StepDefinitions with.
